# Are different port numbers assigned for different tabs opened in a browser

Tags: browser, port

I want to know if different port numbers are assigned to different tabs opened in
a browser. Since on a network every tab inside a browser is running a different process,there must be some way to differentiate between them.

But i want to clear my concept on this fact ??

Comment: "every tab inside a browser is running a different process" is not true. Some browsers run all tabs in the same process.

Comment: I want to say that for example inside a tab iam downloading from a website 'a' and inside another tab iam downloading from website 'b'. Then how does data which reached to my IP address gets to know that it is destined for which process ??

Comment: Unfortunately, "process" has a standard meaning in IT referring to a routine that is running. If you mean that, then no, no processes must be identified. What you are referring to is connection, and one process can have many of them. But you can easily check your ports by calling netstat -na and compare the result with your tabs.

Comment: When i type netstat -na in my command prompt,the outpur gets visible for a fraction of second and then goes off.What is the remedy of this ??

Comment: Check out [Do Web browsers use different port numbers for open tabs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6632801/do-web-browsers-use-different-port-numbers-for-open-tabs)

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket) you can read more about what is below

On process can listen to one port. And one socket is dedicated for listening. But, a port can handle many sockets transferring data back and forth, a socket is a combination of local IP / port and remote IP address / remote port. In that way once a server accepts the incoming connection while listening it opens a new socket dedicated to that conversation and hands the processing off to somewhere else , then goes back to listening. So it not really a bunch of ports but rather a bunch of sockets.

Hope this helps